# SpringBoot - Feign Client java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I trying call another service to Print my data to excel. im uisng Feign clinet to call thet Service.

Im getting below error while running the application

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body
> parameters: public abstract org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
> com.client.ReportClient.generateReport(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,com.dto.ReportRequestDto)

Below is Feign clinet code.

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/report", produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE,
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            "application/msword"}, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
     ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> generateReport(
            @RequestHeader("Accept") String contentType,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestBody ReportRequestDto body) ;
```

ReportRequestDto

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ReportRequestDto {
    List<Object[]> data;
    List<ReportColumnHeaderDto> columnHeaders;
    Map<String, Object> params;
    Integer columnCount;
    String fileName;
}
```

ReportColumnHeaderDto

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ReportColumnHeaderDto {
    private String columnHeader;
    private String columnWidth;

    public ReportColumnHeaderDto(String columnHeader) {
        this.columnHeader = columnHeader;
    }
}
```

Can you guys Please help me what's wrong with this code

Comment: Please add the **full stacktrace** instead of some arbitrary snippet. I do think however tha tyou cannot include the response in the list of parameters (and what good would it be to a feign client anyway?).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `HttpServletResponse response` parameter - it is your another body. It make sense for server method to have `HttpServletResponse` as a parameter, but Feign cannot do much with it. Return value is your response.